# Unable to start a virtual machine on Virtualbox - Ubuntu 18.04 - infamous problem - no solution works

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04, homestead

While trying to use Laravel's Homestead environment, I had to install vagrant and virtualbox.
I already had an older version of Virtualbox.
uninstalled it and installed a new one, then installed Vagrant.

While trying to start my virtual machine I've got a well known issue:

[image: Error msg]

For the past 2 days I've tried EVERYTHING 
I've tried

```
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

which didn't work, So as suggested in a few posts, I've disabled secure boot from the BIOS.
It still didn't work.

I've tried every type of uninstalling with apt, apt-get and dpkg for everything that includes "virtualbox" in it's package name. Also purged, autoremove and autoclean everything possible.
I've checked the lists and seems like I'm all clean of virtualbox.
But when I'm installing it again directly from the VB website with an installer (version 6.1) it happens again and again.

Funny thing is that no matter how much I clean or purge, whenever I'm installing it again, all my virtual machines are still there. meaning there's still something I'm missing...

**Please help. Thanks a LOT!**

I've read just about everything about it including:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163267/virtual-box-works-no-longer-suspect-a-kernel-update-caused-this

http://mitreasorin.blogspot.com/2016/08/upgrade-virtualbox-rtr3initex-failed.html

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=79035

[Unable to start Vagrant VirtualBox on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48994183/unable-to-start-vagrant-virtualbox-on-ubuntu/49038624#49038624)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163267/virtual-box-works-no-longer-suspect-a-kernel-update-caused-this

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=292858 (for /sbin/vboxconfig that didn't work)

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/virtualbox-not-working-cant-rmmod-vboxdrv/86277

**And a lot more. too many to mention**, it's just about repeating the same things.

Comment: Try https://askubuntu.com/a/82145/546023 and if your current Kernel is one that is compiled with VBox modules try one that is not.

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you. The grub update output is as followes: Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-96-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-96-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-33-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-33-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration.
How doe's it help? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't really help much but you can always try a fresh reinstall of the kernel itself along with trying to unload the vbox kernel module ([try this](https://opensource.com/article/18/5/how-load-or-unload-linux-kernel-module)) and reinstall vbox after doing all this

Comment: @apokryfos, well it didn't help me find where are the mods, but following it I've read through [this](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=49080) but I didn't find anything related to vbox what so ever :'(

Comment: Well ... you can always backup your data, format and reinstall probably going to be easier than going deeper in this rabbit hole

Comment: Probably... Knowing myself, I'll get stuck with it somehow, and after 2 additional days I'll have a fresh new installation with the same problem :D anyway, thank you!