# virtualbox inaccessible and genymotion unable to load

Tags: java, android, virtualbox, genymotion

Greetings to all I hope you have a good day , not like me.i have captive genymotion.My genymotion has been broken and disabled. I do not know what to do. I went a few places for solve  this problem But I did not answer .my os win7.

### Error

Unable to start the virtual device.
VirtualBox cannot start the virtual device.
To find out the cause of the problem, start the virtual device from VirtualBox.
For more information, check the log files.

---

ok when start the virtual device from VirtualBox this message show for my:

---

Failed to create the VirtualBoxClient COM object.
The application will now terminate.
Callee RC: REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG (0x80040154)

---

and again message:

---

Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Samsung Galaxy Note 3 - 4.4.4 - API 19 - 1080x1920.
The virtual machine 'Samsung Galaxy Note 3 - 4.4.4 - API 19 - 1080x1920' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).  More details may be available in 'C:\Users\Rad\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed\Samsung Galaxy Note 3 - 4.4.4 - API 19 - 1080x1920\Logs\VBoxStartup.log'.
Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: MachineWrap
Interface: IMachine {f30138d4-e5ea-4b3a-8858-a059de4c93fd}

---

and virtualbox error :

for virtualbox is Start tag expected, '<' not found.

Location: 'C:\Users\Rad\VirtualBox VMs\genymotion_vbox86p_4.4.2_140524_040850\genymotion_vbox86p_4.4.2_140524_040850.vbox', line 1 (0), column 1.
D:\tinderbox\win-4.2\src\VBox\Main\src-server\MachineImpl.cpp[725] (long __cdecl Machine::registeredInit(void)).
Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
Machine
Interface: 
IMachine {22781af3-1c96-4126-9edf-67a020e0e858}

[how to copy file to file?!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217193/oracle-virtual-box-inaccessible)

Answer (score 3):

All the problems were solved by changing the version of virtualbox .

version of  VirtualBox-4.3.2-90405-Win

and

version of  Genymotion.v2.5.3-vbox